# How can I link button onclick to slide to the next panel horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, translate-animation

Right now my webpage has vertical snap to scroll to each of the three 100vh sections.

In the second section, I have 3 100vw divs lined up horizontally with { overflow-x: scroll }. So I went ahead and try to link the my button that would help translate x using the following code:

```
const button = document.getElementById('slide');

button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('wrapper').scrollLeft += 20;
};
```

I guess right now the numbers doesn't matter. I just want to see it moving, but I can't get it to move on-click. Any ideas?

```
codepen.io/brandoniscool/pen/vYBMZyM
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just as a link to codepen. And explain your problem in more detail, "having trouble getting it to work" is not a good explanation.

Comment: My bad, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300% width is set on the wrapper, so it is the wrapper parent (id special) which needs to scroll.
Setting scrollLeft on the special element works as expected. `document.getElementById('special').scrollLeft += 20;`

```js
const button = document.getElementById('slide');

button.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('special').scrollLeft += 20;
};
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}

body {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;

}

section {
 scroll-snap-align: start;
 height: 100vh;
 outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
 background-color: #c1d37f;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}



.verticalSection {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 height: inherit;
 border: 0.5px dashed #664e4c;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  /* so the border doesnt increase over the 100% width and heights */
}


#wrapper {
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 display: flex;
}

.horizontalSection {
 
 background-color: #f9d4bb;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
 border: 0.5px dashed #664e4c;
 box-sizing: border-box; /* so the border doesnt increase over the 100% width and heights */
}

h1 {
 color: #664e4c;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>vertical snap and horizontal snap integration</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <div class="verticalSection"> <h1> BOX 1</h1> </div>
 </section>
 <section id="special">
  <div id="wrapper">
   
   <div class="horizontalSection"> <h1> BOX 2.1</h1> <button id="slide" type="button">Next</button></div>
   <div class="horizontalSection"> <h1> BOX 2.2</h1> </div>
   <div class="horizontalSection"> <h1> BOX 2.3</h1> </div>

  </div>
  
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="verticalSection"> <h1> BOX 3</h1> </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```